# _CrtSetReportHook does not work with windows service

Tags: c++

We have a windows Service written with C++. This service is crashing in some production sites and an application crash message box is popped up that is waiting for users to click ok on. We are deploying debug version of this service for some reason. I am trying to find a solution to disable messagebox that has Abort, Retry, Ignore button but nothing is working. I want the service to crash without message box so our Daemon service can start it back automatically. So far I have tried

1. SetErrorMode
2. _CrtSetReportMode
3. _CrtSetReportHook

But are not working. Looks like all these things work only from console application. When I use these, my application is not popping messagebox but also not exiting. Any help would be great. Note that OS is windows Server 2003

Comment: "We are deploying debug version of this service for some reason."  Do not do that.  The debug CRT is not intended to be redistributed.

Comment: To answer your question, though, we need to know what is causing the error message to be displayed.  Is it an assertion raise from user code?  Is it an assertion raised from within the CRT?  Is the invalid parameter handler being invoked?  Has the debug heap detected corruption?  Is the error actually coming from the CRT, or is it coming from some other component in the process?

Comment: Basically these are heap and stack corruption popup messages. They are coming from CRT. The service itself is not using any other components, it has different threads doing different work

Comment: Agree with James. There's nothing wrong with defining another configuration between Debug & Release, which (like Debug) uses no optimizations and (like Release) links against the redistributable CRT. The current scenario is flat out unsupported; you're getting errors from a debug CRT that is by definition improperly installed.

Comment: How to define such a configuration? This C++ service with VS 2003